# Divs are not flipping on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Pre-story:** I am using CSS and jQuery to create a flipping effect.

**How I am achieving it:** For that purpose I am using preserve-3d.

**Good news:** It works all fine on all major browsers

**Problem:** It does not work in IE.

**Solution approach:** Initially I thought it is not applying the preserve but then I think it is just not firing the back element.

**Help:** Can you please help, link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/qsQun/)

```js
function flip() {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="flip()">flip the card</button>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Teemu not sure how to relate it to my code

Comment: The transform-style CSS property is not compatible with Internet Explorer, @John .

Comment: `transform-style` is a crucial CSS property, which makes your code to work, and not supported in IEs, as you can read at the linked MDN page, or in Alexandre's comment.

Comment: @Alexandre can I replace it in IE?

Comment: @John Internet Explorer doesn't yet support this (And I quote) "experimental technology".

Comment: @Alexandre IE doesn't even support 2d transforms fully, how would you except it to support 3d

Comment: IE should be used to download Chrome or Firefox. Unfortunately, MAJOR BROWSERS includes Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer is always 5 years behind recent technologies. They will tell you to upgrade to windows 10 to get those features with Edge lol. @Bálint indeed I don't expect anything out of IE except it should work to get on chrome webpage to download it.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the remarks it's a compatibility issue with IE.

I suggest a simple workaround, hoping it could help:

```js
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = (ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) ? true : false;
var i = 0;

function flip() {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
  if (msie) {
    // the timeout happens after 400ms because on my computer this create the right effect
    i = (i + 1) % 2;
    setTimeout(function (i) {
      $('.card > div:eq(' + i + ')').css('backface-visibility', 'visible');
      $('.card > div:not(:eq(' + i + '))').css('backface-visibility', 'hidden');
    }, 400, i);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="flip()">flip the card</button>
<section class="container">
    <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
        <div class="front">1</div>
        <div class="back">2</div>
    </div>
</section>
```